# Session Fixation Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sessionid

In one of our application we are facing below issue related `SessionId`.
`SessionId` value in cookie (Request & Response body) are not regenerating new values once user logoff from application and logins back (I mean signing off from application without closing browser and singing in back). Its maintaining earlier values, instead of generating new values.

But if close browser it's generating new values. But we wanted to generate new `SessionId` values every time user logoff from application and logins back.

We tried to clear cookie values in Logout handler

```
Httpcontext.Current.Request.Cookies.Clear();
```

and Added expiration date to cookies like as

```
Response.Cookies["SessionID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

But even after making these changes also we are not getting a new `Sessionid` value after logout and login.

Comment: Could you post code of your logout method?

Comment: Make sure your cookie is persistent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869821/how-do-i-create-a-persistent-vs-a-non-persistent-cookie